# Overloading external C++ classes to be called from Qt Application

Tags: c++, qt, class, overloading

I am using an API (Insta360 SDK) with Qt.
To retrieve pictures, I must override a class called 'StreamDelegate'. I want to add a new method (ie setupThread) in this class, in order to call another object.
In the parent object, I am stuck with some casting issues, as seen below :

The overloaded StreamDelegate class :

```c
class TestStreamDelegate: public ins_camera::StreamDelegate {
public:
 TestStreamDelegate( ) {
   file1_ = fopen("gyro.txt", "w");
   file2_ = fopen("exposure.txt", "w");
   filel_ = fopen("left.h264", "w");
   filer_ = fopen("right.h264", "w");
 }

 ~TestStreamDelegate() {
   fclose(file1_);
   fclose(file2_);
 }

 // NEW FUNCTION TO ADD !!
 void setupThread(QString str) {

 }

 void OnAudioData(const uint8_t* data, size_t size, int64_t timestamp) override {
   std::cout << "on audio data:" << std::endl;
 }

 void OnVideoData(const uint8_t* data, size_t size, int64_t timestamp, uint8_t streamType, int stream_index = 0) override {

   QByteArray ba(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(data), size );
   //emit resultEncodedPicture( ba );

   std::cout << "on video frame:" << size << ";" << timestamp << std::endl;
   if(stream_index == 0) {
     fwrite(data, sizeof(uint8_t), size, filel_);
   }
   if (stream_index == 1) {
     fwrite(data, sizeof(uint8_t), size, filer_);
   }
 }

 void OnGyroData(const std::vector<ins_camera::GyroData>& data) override {

   for (auto& gyro : data) {
     if (gyro.timestamp - last_timestamp > 2) {
       fprintf(file1_, "timestamp:%lld package_size = %d  offtimestamp = %lld gyro:[%f %f %f] accel:[%f %f %f]\n", gyro.timestamp, data.size(), gyro.timestamp - last_timestamp, gyro.gx, gyro.gy, gyro.gz, gyro.ax, gyro.ay, gyro.az);
     }
     last_timestamp = gyro.timestamp;
   }
 }

 void OnExposureData(const ins_camera::ExposureData& data) override {
   fprintf(file2_, "timestamp:%lld shutter_speed_s:%f\n", data.timestamp, data.exposure_time);
 }

private:
 FILE* file1_;
 FILE* file2_;
 FILE* filel_;
 FILE* filer_;
 int64_t last_timestamp = 0;
};
```

The parent code :

```c
  std::shared_ptr<ins_camera::StreamDelegate> delegate = std::make_shared<TestStreamDelegate>( );
delegate->setupThread( "TEST" ); // THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK
  camera->SetStreamDelegate(delegate);
```

I am getting the following error :

```
insta360controller.cpp:94:13: error: no member named 'setupThread' in 'ins_camera::StreamDelegate'
```

I suspect the solution is pretty simple, but I am completly blocked with this kind of "type" conversion. Help will be really appreciated :) !

Comment: I assume you don't want to use `std::shared_ptr<TestStreamDelegate> delegate = std::make_shared<TestStreamDelegate>( );`

Comment: A `std::shared_ptr<ins_camera::StreamDelegate>` will only expose the interface provided by `ins_camera::StreamDelegate`.  It has no way to guarantee that it's pointing to a more derived object with additional functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In fact, I must use - as far as I know - ```std::shared_ptr<ins_camera::StreamDelegate>``` because the ```camera->SetStreamDelegate()``` needs it.

Comment: Where do you plan on calling this function? Is it in your code? Or something the camera will call?

Comment: To be precise : the StreamDelegate class is going to be called by the Camera SDK. This is why it needs to be registered thru the ```SetStreamDelegate()``` call.

Comment: If I use TestStreamDelegate like this : 

```c
 std::shared_ptr<TestStreamDelegate> delegate = std::make_shared<TestStreamDelegate>( );
  delegate->setupThread( "TEST");
  camera->SetStreamDelegate(delegate);
```

Then the error is : 

```
insta360controller.cpp:95:29: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'shared_ptr<ins_camera::StreamDelegate>' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'shared_ptr<TestStreamDelegate>'
camera.h:133:65: note: passing argument to parameter 'delegate' here
```

Comment: Of course it does not work. You say `std::shared_ptr<ins_camera::StreamDelegate> delegate = ...`, which means "forget everything in the right-hand side that is not a `StreamDelegate`, I will only use the `StreamDelegate` part of it". And then you immediately proceed to use something that is not in `StreamDelegate`. What did you expect? If you need to use `TestStreamDelegate`, say so: `std::shared_ptr<TestStreamDelegate> delegate = ...`.

Comment: Yes, understood, but in that case, the SetStreamDelegate() function needs a ```std::shared_ptr<ins_camera::StreamDelegate>``` function. So how to deal with both ?

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<TestStreamDelegate>` is convertible to `std::shared_ptr<ins_camera::StreamDelegate>`, so just pass it to that function. Not sure what your problem is.

Comment: When I try this, I got an error. How do you convert it ? Thru a kind of casting ? If yes, which one ?

Comment: You need to show the exact unedited text of the error message in the question. Also post the declaration of `SetStreamDelegate()`.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer, I finally solved my issue with a proper casting !

Comment: "proper casting" is an oxymoron, most of the time. Chances are you are masking a bug.